# Обьединение bitbucket и github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Вообщем, есть ли какой-то способ обьединить эти две системы, что б с помощью статистики в гитхабе видеть активность коммитов на bitbucket? То есть я работаю на bitbucket, а на гитхабе в статистике отображается что сколько я комитов делал в день. Пока попробовал привязать гит на одну почту и гитхаб и bitbucket, но пока не сработало, думаю над дубликатом репозитория с bitbucket  на гитхаб, но может есть варианты полегче?

Comment: Ну как вариант действительно дубликат репозитория, плюс какая-то автоматизация, которая будет синхронизировать коммиты.

Comment: @insolor никакая автоматизация не требуется, ``git push all $branchname$`` пушит сразу во все удаленные репозитории. Надо их сначала настроить, конечно.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а, ну или так, так даже проще. Я просто сталкивался с проектом, который лежал на github и bitbucket (причем на bb был mercurial репозиторий, тогда bb еще поддерживал mercurial), и коммиты синхронизировались между репозиториями. Если в обоих местах git, так конечно проще.